# For end-cloud collaboration scenario in Apache IoTDB, how to check and change the flush frequency?

Tags: database, flush, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I realized that Apache IoTDB can execute in end-cloud collaboration scenario, but I wonder how often will flush be executed by default in this scenario? Also, are there a parameter to modify the default flush and synchronization frequency, and how should I change it?